# Javascript Los GIFs reinician su animación cuando los coloco varias veces

Tags: javascript, gif

Tengo un problema con el GIF utilizado en el siguiente código:

```
let screenHTML = document.getElementById("screen");

let meteorGenerator = (id) => {
    let xPos = (Math.random() + Math.random())/2 * screenHTML.offsetWidth;
    let yPos = (Math.random() + Math.random())/2 * screenHTML.offsetHeight;

    console.log(`${xPos}, ${yPos}`);

    // Creamos el meteorito y le ponemos el id y la clase
    var newMeteor = document.createElement("img");
    newMeteor.id = `meteor${id}`;
    newMeteor.classList.add("meteor");

    // Añadimos la imagen de la sombra
    newMeteor.src = "assets/meteor_shadow_center.png";

    //Añadimos la posición del meteorito
    newMeteor.style.marginLeft = `${xPos}px`;
    newMeteor.style.marginTop = `${yPos}px`;

    // Añadimos el meteor a la pantalla
    screenHTML.appendChild(newMeteor);

    // Cuando pase 1 segundo tendremos la explosión del meteorito
    setTimeout( () => {
        document.getElementById(`meteor${id}`).src = "assets/meteor_explosion_oneloop_center.gif";
        console.log(id);
    }, 1000, id); // Pasamos la id como parametro
}

let init_id = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    meteorGenerator(init_id);
    init_id = init_id + 1;
}, 100, init_id)
```

```
body{
    background-color: #404040;
}

#screen{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #202020;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.meteor{
    transform: translate(-50%, -65%);
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: meteor;
    animation-duration:2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

@keyframes meteor {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="screen">

    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El programa lo que busca hacer es generar caídas aleatorias de meteoritos dentro de la pantalla. Cuando cae el meteorito utilizo Javascript para cambiar la fuente de la imagen (al principio es la sombra del meteorito) al GIF que es la animación de la explosión. El problema es que cuando cambio una de las imágenes al GIF de la explosión los otros GIFs que ya han finalizado su animación (el GIF es de un único loop) vuelven a iniciar la animación. Este reinicio de animación lo hacen todos los GIFs de forma totalmente coordinada.

Os dejo una muestra de lo que me pasa:
https://i.gyazo.com/32232bf1a49d4301765dd955ea162fab.gif

Answer (score 1):

El problema que yo veo es que vas agregando imágenes con los GIF, y nunca los eliminas, razón por la cual siempre se están reciclándose.

Lo que yo te recomiendo, agrega otro timeout, calculando el tiempo de tu animación y elimina el ítem.

Y otra cosa que agregue es un querystring a el gif, para que el navegador lo detecte como diferente y no como la misma imagen, y vuelva a cargar el archivo.

```js
window.onload = function (e) {

    let screenHTML = document.getElementById("screen");

    let meteorGenerator = (id) => {
        let xPos = (Math.random() + Math.random()) / 2 * screenHTML.offsetWidth;
        let yPos = (Math.random() + Math.random()) / 2 * screenHTML.offsetHeight;

        console.log(`${xPos}, ${yPos}`);

        // Creamos el meteorito y le ponemos el id y la clase
        var newMeteor = document.createElement("img");
        newMeteor.id = `meteor${id}`;
        newMeteor.classList.add("meteor");

        // Añadimos la imagen de la sombra
        newMeteor.src = "https://i.postimg.cc/Mfm7P9v1/meteor-shadow-center.png";

        //Añadimos la posición del meteorito
        newMeteor.style.marginLeft = `${xPos}px`;
        newMeteor.style.marginTop = `${yPos}px`;

        // Añadimos el meteor a la pantalla
        screenHTML.appendChild(newMeteor);

        // Cuando pase 1 segundo tendremos la explosión del meteorito
        setTimeout(() => {
            //Le asigno un querystring, que sea diferente para que no cargue de nuevo la misma imagen.
            document.getElementById(`meteor${id}`).src = `https://i.postimg.cc/xN2G3wT0/meteor-explosion-oneloop-center.gif?id=${id}-${xPos}-${yPos}`;
            //Asigno un timeout para eliminarlo
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.getElementById(`meteor${id}`).remove();
            }, 700);
            console.log(id);
        }, 500, id); // Pasamos la id como parametro
    }

    let init_id = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
        meteorGenerator(init_id);
        init_id = init_id + 1;
    }, 600, init_id)
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #404040;
}

#screen {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #202020;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.meteor {
    transform: translate(-50%, -65%);
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: meteor;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

@keyframes meteor {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="screen">

    </div>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

.